# adding two matrices in c++ in two different ways

Tags: c++

I just wondering if there is a deference between two scenarios

first code is if the outer for counting the rows and the inner one counting the cols

second code is if the outer for counting the cols and the inner one counting the rows

I apply the two and get the same results

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You'll get same result, but you might get different performance.

Matrices most likely stored in row-major order and accessing it by rows might get better memory bandwidth and $ utilization. Just try doing the same for huge matrices and measure the walltime.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

Comment: I do not think it would matter, in both ways, we have random access, and we still iterate through every n^2 element. I am not sure if I understand the difference.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR It's not random access, it's sequential vs strided.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to time it. First, my results. The reported numbers are average CPU clock cycles for 10000 trials.

```
$ clang++ -Ofast -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 mat_add.cpp -o mat_add && ./mat_add
avg. cycles 100x100 doubles matrix addition
strided:    60149
sequential: 27137
$ g++-4.9 -Ofast -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 mat_add.cpp -o mat_add && ./mat_add
avg. cycles 100x100 doubles matrix addition
strided:    90517
sequential: 33407
```

Sequential access is faster. The reason is caching behavior, in particular cachelines. Here's an interesting read on the subject.

http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/

I distinguish between strided and sequential rather than rows and columns because rows and columns are arbitrary. Usually in C++ we think of sequential elements as being in the same row but this is purely convention and is not inherent in the language. Different libraries follow different conventions.

Test code.

```
// timing
// http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf
#include <stdlib.h>
uint64_t start, stop;
unsigned cycles_high;
unsigned cycles_low;
unsigned cycles_high1;
unsigned cycles_low1;
unsigned ellapsed_cycles;

static inline void start_count()
{
    asm volatile(
        "CPUID\n\t"
        "RDTSC\n\t"
        "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %1\n\t"
        : "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low)
        :
        : "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
}

static inline void stop_count()
{
    asm volatile(
        "RDTSCP\n\t"
        "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %1\n\t"
        "CPUID\n\t"
        : "=r" (cycles_high1), "=r" (cycles_low1)
        :
        : "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    start = ( ((uint64_t)cycles_high << 32) | cycles_low );
    stop = ( ((uint64_t)cycles_high1 << 32) | cycles_low1 );
    ellapsed_cycles = stop - start;
}


// matrix addition
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <random>

using std::size_t;

template<class T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(const size_t n, const size_t m)
    : elems_(new T[n*m]), n_(n), m_(m)
    {}

    Matrix(const size_t n, const size_t m, const std::vector< std::vector<T> >& elems)
    : elems_(new T[n*m]), n_(n), m_(m)
    {
        assert(n != 0 && m != 0);
        for (size_t i = 0; i != n_; ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j != m_; ++j)
            {
                std::cout << "elems[" << n << ", " << j << "] = " << elems[i][j] << std::endl;
                elems_[i*n + j] = elems[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    ~Matrix()
    {
        delete[] elems_;
    };

    T& operator()(const size_t i, size_t j)
    {
        assert(i < n_ && j < m_);
        return elems_[i*m_ + j];
    }

    const T& operator()(const size_t i, size_t j) const
    {
        assert(i < n_ && j < m_);
        return elems_[i*m_ + j];
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix& mat)
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        size_t j = 0;
        os << "[ ";
        goto first;
        for (; i != mat.n_; ++i)
        {
            os << "  ";
            first:
            for (j = 0; j != mat.m_; ++j)
            {
                // make it all pretty and nice
                os << std::fixed;
                os.width(6);
                os.precision(2);
                os << mat(i, j) << " ";
            }
            if (i != mat.n_ - 1)
                os << "\n";
        }
        os << " ]";
        return os;
    }

    size_t n() const { return n_; }
    size_t m() const { return m_; }

private:
    T* elems_;
    const size_t n_;
    const size_t m_;
};


template<class T>
Matrix<T> add_sequential(const Matrix<T>& mat1, const Matrix<T>& mat2)
{
    assert(mat1.n() == mat2.n() && mat1.m() == mat2.m());
    const size_t n = mat1.n();
    const size_t m = mat1.m();
    Matrix<T> sum(n, m);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j != m; ++j)
        {
            sum(i, j) = mat1(i, j) + mat2(i, j);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

template<class T>
Matrix<T> add_strided(const Matrix<T>& mat1, const Matrix<T>& mat2)
{
    assert(mat1.n() == mat2.n() && mat1.m() == mat2.m());
    const size_t n = mat1.n();
    const size_t m = mat1.m();
    Matrix<T> sum(n, m);
    for (size_t j = 0; j != m; ++j)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i)
        {
            sum(i, j) = mat1(i, j) + mat2(i, j);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}


// misc: making random matrices, flushing cache, running timing tests
template<class T>
Matrix<T> rand_real_mat(const size_t n, const size_t m)
{
    static std::default_random_engine gen;
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dis(-100.0, 100.0);
    Matrix<T> mat(n, m);
    for (size_t j = 0; j != m; ++j)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i)
        {
            mat(i, j) = dis(gen);
        }
    }
    return mat;
}


#include <fstream>
void flush_cache()
{
    std::ifstream rand("/dev/random", std::ifstream::binary);
    std::ofstream devnull("/dev/null", std::ofstream::binary);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != (30 * 1024 / sizeof(int)); ++i)
    {
        int r;
        rand >> r;
        devnull << r;
    }
}

template<class R, class ElemType>
static inline std::vector<uint64_t> time_mat_fnc(
    R (fnc)(const Matrix<ElemType>&, const Matrix<ElemType>&),
    const size_t n_times)
{
    std::ofstream devnull("/dev/null", std::ofstream::binary);

    std::vector<uint64_t> times;
    times.reserve(n_times);
    static const size_t n = 100;
    static const size_t m = 100;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
    {
        // create 2 random n x m matrices
        const auto m1 = rand_real_mat<ElemType>(n, m);
        const auto m2 = rand_real_mat<ElemType>(n, m);

        flush_cache();

        // addition
        start_count();
        const auto sum = fnc(m1, m2);
        stop_count();
        times.push_back(ellapsed_cycles);

        // prevent optimizing away unused result
        devnull << sum;
    }
    return times;
}

template<typename C>
decltype(std::declval<typename C::value_type>()/std::declval<typename C::value_type>())
average(const C& cntnr)
{
    typename C::value_type sum = 0;
    size_t size = 0;
    for (typename C::const_iterator it = cntnr.begin(), end = cntnr.end(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        sum += *it;
        ++size;
    }
    return sum / size;
}

int main()
{
    typedef double ElemType;
    const size_t trials = 10000;
    const std::vector<uint64_t> strided_times = time_mat_fnc(add_strided<ElemType>, trials);
    const std::vector<uint64_t> sequential_times = time_mat_fnc(add_sequential<ElemType>, trials);

    const auto strided_avg = average(strided_times);
    const auto sequential_avg = average(sequential_times);

    std::cout << "avg. cycles 100x100 doubles matrix addition" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "strided:    " << strided_avg << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sequential: " << sequential_avg << std::endl;
}
```